# Avro serialization in Node.js

Tags: node.js, serialization, avro

I have to serialize a Json using Avro in Node.js. For this I used [node-avro-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-avro-io) package using help from [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935558/serializing-data-with-avro-in-node-js). But the serialized data using this contains schema with each serialized Json. Is there a way I could do it without adding schema to each serialized JSON. In Java I was able to achieve it by directly operating upon Datum Writer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but [`avsc`](https://github.com/mtth/avsc) should let you do what you want. (The [quickstart guide](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki) might be a good place to start.)